# Logging is not working with dataflow version 2.8

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

When I run my dataflow job with sdk version 2.9.0 , my dataflow job logs information but when I switch to 2.8.0 logger doesn't work...

```py
logging.info(row)
```

This code just prints the line by line data...

The log in dataflow should print the rows in log messages on console even when I am using sdk 2.8.0..

Comment: Just wondering if 2.9.0 works, why not use 2.9.0 directly? Is there a reason that you have to use 2.8.0?

Comment: I am switching to 2.8.0 by installing apache_beam

Comment: yes Rui Wang...I am runing this dataflow templates with composer which has 2.8.0 installed on it...And dataflow job fails with composer if I switch to 2.9.0 on composer

Comment: Hi @SURAJMANIYAR, can you please edit your question with what language you are using, the shortest code necessary to reproduce the logging error, and any relevant configuration and depedency changes you made. I haven't seen this bug before and it may be due to some dependency/config errors.

As an FYI, even if we find the bug, Apache Beam doesn't back-fix. So you will either have to downgrade to 2.7.1 (the LTS version) or upgrade to a newer version.